# patchcmd, #1 as hook, and AtEndPreamble

Tags: macros, biblatex, etoolbox, patching

I'm trying to patch some `bidi` footnote commands (`\@footnotetext`, `\@LTRfootnotetext`, and `\@RTLfootnotetext`) in `biblatex`.

The footnote patching commands in `biblatex` occur in an `AtEndPreamble` macro in `biblatex.sty`.

And I'm trying to use `#1` as a hook in `\patchcmd`.

This is a combination which fails, and I'm looking for ideas as to the best way around the problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bidi}
\tracingpatches
\newtoggle{blx@footnote}
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \patchcmd\@footnotetext
    {#1}
    {\toggletrue{blx@footnote}#1}
    {\def\patchresult{success}}
    {\def\patchresult{failure}}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\patchresult
\end{document}
```

`\@footnotetext` is defined this way in `bidi`:

```
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \footdir@write
  \footdir@fntext{\bidi@footdir@footnote}%
  \stepcounter{footdir@label}%
  \footdir@fntext{\bidi@footdir@footnote}%
  \footdir@toks{#1}%
  \footdir@toks\expandafter
    {\the\expandafter\footdir@toks
     \expandafter \zref@labelbyprops
     \expandafter{\thefootdir@label}{abspage}}%
     \expandafter\footdir@ORG@bidi@footnotetext
     \expandafter{\the\footdir@toks}}
```

This is in order to fix issue #412 in `biblatex`. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/412